# How to validate different redux-form fields depending on action?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

Say I have a form with fields `fileNames` and `recipientEmail` and two buttons `"Download"` and `"Send Email"`

How can `fileNames` be always validated, but `recipientEmail` only on email sending?

I do not want to add a checkbox like "I have to check this to be able to send an email"